# SQL error "29 FEB 1986" as null

Tags: sql, datetime

I tried converting 29 FEB 1986 to datetime, but I cant seem to do it.
I used

```
cast('2/29/1986' as datetime)
```

and that doesnt work as it returns null. But it works for years after 2004 like

```
cast('2/29/2004' as datetime)
```

any suggestions how i can cast it

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert it because it's not a valid date.

`1986-02-29` is not a valid date, as `1986` was not a [leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

Additionally, `2004-02-29` *does* work, because it *was* a leap year.